# Is it possible to make a True Color RGB with 2 VIS band and one IR band?

Tags: modis, color, rgb

I want to create a True colour RGB. I am working with MODIS L1 images. For some circumstances, the only bands that I have available are:

- Band 1 (620 - 670) (VIS)
- Band 2 (841 - 876) (VIS)
- Band 22 emissive (3.9)
- Band 26 (1.36 - 1.39)
- Band 29 (8.4 - 8.7)
- Band 34 (13.485 - 13.785)

Is there any way to produce a True Color RGB  image using 3 of these bands?
I know that a NIR band (0.89) can be used to produce a fake Green, but I haven't found a "recipe" like this to produce something similar with one of the bands I have available.

Comment: Perhaps you could try the old SPOT 5 [natural color equation](https://www.globalmapperforum.com/discussion/923/colour-mapping-for-spot-satellite-bands)